# Openldap Master/Slave replication removing cn & gidNumber from group (on slvae) instead of just a member

Tags: openldap

I have configured a second Openldap server to be a slave of the first:
(Overlay was already enabled)

```
dn: olcDatabase={2}bdb,cn=config
changetype: modify
add:olcSyncrepl
olcSyncrepl: {0}rid=001 provider=ldap://******* binddn="cn=*****,dc=*****,dc=*****,dc=***,dc=**" bindmethod=simple credentials=***** searchbase="dc=***,dc=****,dc=**,dc=**" type=refreshAndPersist retry="5 5 300 +" timeout=1
```

When I test by deleting a `memberUid` from a group on the first server, the second server sees this & goes a bit further by also deleting the groups `gidNumber` and its `cn`

> Dec 19 13:11:43 dev-util2 slapd[8082]: syncrepl_entry: rid=001 be_search (0)
>   Dec 19 13:11:43 dev-util2 slapd[8082]: syncrepl_entry: rid=001 cn=*****,ou=***,dc=***,dc=***,dc=**,dc=**
>   Dec 19 13:11:43 dev-util2 slapd[8082]: slap_queue_csn: queueing 0x7f69f410ce90 20191219131141.244487Z#000000#000#000000
>   Dec 19 13:11:43 dev-util2 slapd[8082]: slap_graduate_commit_csn: removing 0x7f69f410ce90 20191219131141.244487Z#000000#000#000000
>   Dec 19 13:11:43 dev-util2 slapd[8082]: syncrepl_entry: rid=001 be_modify cn=*******,ou=Group,dc=***,dc=****,dc=**,dc=** (0)
>   Dec 19 13:11:43 dev-util2 slapd[8082]: slap_queue_csn: queueing 0x7f69f4001d20 20191219131141.244487Z#000000#000#000000
>   Dec 19 13:11:43 dev-util2 slapd[8082]: slap_graduate_commit_csn: removing 0x7f69f4001d20 20191219131141.244487Z#000000#000#000000

Any advice/help may be very useful

Comment: Also am seeing on masterDec 23 12:29:19 DEV-mgt slapd[11678]: <= bdb_equality_candidates: (entryUUID) not indexedDec 23 12:29:19 DEV-mgt slapd[11678]: <= bdb_equality_candidates: (entryCSN) not indexed

Comment: syncrepl_del_nonpresent
is reported on slave just before it deletes data it should not

Comment: You should really index both `entryUUID` and `entryCSN` when doing replication.

Comment: This error message i hope is a greta clue:entry failed schema check: naming attribute 'cn' is not present in entry

Comment: Entry (ou=idmap,dc=hpc,dc=qmul,dc=ac,dc=uk): object class 'organizationalRole' requires attribute 'cn'